# Auto restart rc.local script on crash

Tags: services, restart, autostart

I have rc.local loading a script on start up. Wondering if this service crashes is there a way to have it auto restart?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu Version 16.04.

Comment: And what does the command in `/etc/rc.local` look like?

Comment: Turn it into a service.

Comment: Its a comand that loads a script which then opens a terminal and enters some commands. example sudo ./app -c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `/etc/rc.local` for long-running services, create [a systemd service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). As an example, create `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service`, containing:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep 10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This creates a service that will restart the command when it dies. Replace `ExecStart` with your command.

After creating this file, do:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable foo.service
sudo systemctl start foo.service
```

The first command will tell `systemctl` to look for new service definitions. The second enables the service according to the startup conditions it has (in this case, to start with the `default.target`, so that it starts at boot). The last command starts the service for *this* session.

---

For `Type`:

> If set to `simple` (the default if neither `Type=` nor `BusName=`, but
>   `ExecStart=` are specified), it is expected that the process configured
>   with `ExecStart=` is the main process of the service. In this mode, if
>   the process offers functionality to other processes on the system, its
>   communication channels should be installed before the daemon is
>   started up (e.g. sockets set up by systemd, via socket activation), as
>   systemd will immediately proceed starting follow-up units.
>
> If set to `forking`, it is expected that the process configured with
>   `ExecStart=` will call `fork()` as part of its start-up. The parent
>   process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all
>   communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the
>   main daemon process. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons.
>   If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the `PIDFile=`
>   option, so that systemd can identify the main process of the daemon.
>   systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the
>   parent process exits.

So, if your command forks, then use `Type=forking` and set `PIDFile` if you can.

---

For `WantedBy`, run `systemctl list-units | grep target` to find other available targets that you can use for more fine-grained control.

Comment: can i us ExecStart with a script example.sh ?

Comment: Sure, a script would work. (usual caveats: it is executable, has a correct shebang, etc.)

Comment: Am i suppose to change the default.target ? I followed the steps but its not listed as a running service on start up when i check service --status-all

Comment: @Zanden what if you do `systemctl status foo.service`?

Comment: Seems to try and start but with errors. foo.service: Start request repeated too quickly. and failed to start

Comment: @Zanden the script must be failing immediately

Comment: Yes i found a error in a path in the script  from moving from pc to VM. Thanks for your time